# How to perform the Friedman test and post-hoc test in Python?

Tags: python, statistical-test

I know that Python's SciPy library has the function for the [Friedman test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.friedmanchisquare.html)

But, it is not enough as I need more information for posthoc test.

So, how I do Friedman test and posthoc test (e.g. Nemenyi or Bonferroni-Dunn test) and draw a critical difference diagram entirely on Python?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the posthoc tests with the [scikit-posthocs](https://github.com/maximtrp/scikit-posthocs) package or with the [STAC](http://tec.citius.usc.es/stac/doc/index.html#) library.

I use Nemenyi's test from scikit-posthocs. They also include a recommendation on how to plot the results.

Comment: Is that STAC library still maintained?

Comment: Also, how to start using it as the page you have given is just the documentation without any installation instruction.

Comment: @Aqee You can install scikit-posthocs with pip: `pip install scikit-posthocs` - the page does include it. I haven't tried STAC myself.